# Whats the bracha for a line of cocaine?

Tags: halacha, blessing, smell

When one feels the need to stimulate oneself by snorting a line of cocaine, would one say the bracha of *besamim* (spices)?

Thank you in advance, this is not [halacha l'maaseh](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4134/5323).

Comment: Does coke have an aroma like *besamim*, or is it "medicinal" like an asthma inhaler is?

Comment: Illegally produced cocaine smells like whatever volatile chemical solvent they used to finish processing it - usually acetone or some other nasty aromatic chemical.  Before they tightened control of it, they used ether, which left hardly any smell at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's contra halacha to do drugs like cocaine

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I agree.  It is a violation of *ushmartem es nafshoseichem* as well as a violation of *dina demalchusa*

Comment: You say "stimulate yourself." I am as unfamiliar with cocaine as @MonicaCellio is, but I wonder if it would have the same [rules](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13507/5323) as [snuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snuff_(tobacco)).

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Why is a question off topic if it involves something against halakha? I am pretty sure you just made that up. Asking about the halakhic ramification of a forbidden act falls squarely into the realm of questions about Judaism, IMHO.

Comment: @mevaqesh, since it's a subject as taboo as illicit drugs, I'd say it should be closed. This is a question for a Jewish narcotics anonymous group, not J.SE

Comment: @Shokhet has raised an interesting point. Snuff is also a harmful addictive drug (but legal) so there could be an analogy made. It is, however, much closer to its plant of origin than cocaine.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be off-topic because it's against Halacha. The question is simply whether a bracha is made on cocaine. Whether Halacha permits drugs could very well be a part of an answer (mitzvah haba'ah me'aveirah), but that doesn't affect the question itself. How many questions do we have on here about "a guy violated Halacha - what now?"

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt "I'd say it should be closed" Unless you can point to something in FAQs or meta, I don't think that is significant. "This is a question for a Jewish narcotics anonymous group" The fact that some other theoretical group may accept this question has no bearing on whether not it is on topic. I fully agree with DonielF's assessment.

Comment: @donielF I agree, it's whether the bracha should be made or not. Thank you all so for the insights!

Comment: very similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17288/759

Comment: אשר יצר אתכם בדין

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocaine is a [Schedule II substance](https://www.dea.gov/druginfo/ds.shtml), which means that a) it has a high potential for abuse, b) it has some accepted medicinal use for treatment, and c) abuse of the substance can lead to severe psychological or physiological dependence.

It was used as a topical anesthetic and some ENTs used to use it as a means to clear a patient's sinuses when administered in a diluted, liquid form. There's some debate as to whether flavored medications require a *birchas henehenin* which is dependent in part on whether the medication is deemed "objectively" good tasting or only flavored as a means to make taking the medication easier. Cocaine has a bitter taste and is not typically taken orally by itself.

The OP's query concerns nasal ingestion of the powdered form of cocaine; this is not the same as smelling. Additionally, cocaine is described as having a chemical smell which is not typically described as a pleasing scent. Moreover, the numbing effect of the cocaine disables one's ability to smell at all for the duration of the use.

Comment: Also, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52709/14052

Comment: So if it is ingesting, would a shehakol be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Since cocaine is harmful, it would not receive any bracha (cf. [Shulchan Aruch §202:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.202.4?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: Maybe we could say 1: inhaling a substance through the nose as a drug (no smell of fragrances involved) is not a form of halachic eating so it has no brachah. 2: It is very very harmful. So we do not say a blessing on something that detroys one's life. However, harmful alone would not absolve it of a Brachah as long as one got some benefit. Straight pure olive oil and raw barley flour have harmful effect but still require a blessing. see Gem' Brachos 36.